# Migrating ADDS Managed Service from classic to Arm

Tags: azure-active-directory

just wondering if anyone has successfully migrated the ADDS Managed Service from Classic VNET to ARM VNET. I would be grateful if someone can share their steps in deleting the ADDS Managed Service and re-provisioning in ARM.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is not currently supported. Microsoft will deliver a mechanism to migrate your existing managed domain from a classic virtual network to a Resource Manager virtual network in the future.

Reference: [Azure Active Directory Domain Services: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-faqs#can-i-migrate-my-existing-managed-domain-from-a-classic-virtual-network-to-a-resource-manager-virtual-network)